# Use KSP to add extra properties to Compose components

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, jetpack-compose-navigation, kotlin-symbol-processing

I'm learning `Navigating with Compose`.

I found that `@Composable` components should be coupled with routing, but unfortunately, The way `navigation-compose` solves hardcoding is not so perfect. like this:

```kotlin
const val forYouNavigationRoute = "for_you_route"
```

A `@Composable` component is separate from its routing path, and I think it's better for them to be bound together.

I want to implement the following functionality, adding additional properties to `@Composable` components, using it like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavHostController) {...}

fun main(){
  println(HomeScreen.label)
  println(HomeScreen.route)
}
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your own annotation so you can easily locate target composable

```
const val USE_COMPOSABLE_FUNCTION_NAME = "use_function_name
@Target(FUNCTION)
annotation class Route(val route : String = USE_COMPOSABLE_FUNCTION_NAME, val label = USE_COMPOSABLE_FUNCTION_NAME)
```

Then use KSP do find this symbol then use a visitor to visit function declaration in the current file to get the name of the composable function.

Once you have got the function name (or annotation's values `route` and `label`) that is annotated with `@Route`, use code generator to generate object that has the properties you want as stated in

```
fun main(){
  println(HomeScreen.label)
  println(HomeScreen.route)
}
```